# ASP.NET application accessing event log on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, registry, event-log, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

Can anyone explain why the following happens:

My ASP.NET application requires access to Application event log.

1. When I access web application initially, it returns "Security" exception (which is expected, as I haven't granted permissions to write to Application event log yet).
2. Then I give read/write permissions to IIS_IUSRS group on the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog. As a result of this action my web application starts working.
3. Now I remove those permissions I've granted to IIS_IUSRS group. But 
   my web application keeps working (although I'd expect "Security" exception raised again)

So, why web application keeps working, although permissions to write to Application log
have been removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between the permissions required to *create* an event source in the event log, and the permissions required to *write* to an existing event source. A higher permission is needed to create the event source.

Here's a [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649337.aspx) re accessing the event log:

> Least privileged accounts have
>   sufficient permissions to be able to
>   write records to the event log by
>   using existing event sources. However,
>   they do not have sufficient
>   permissions to create new event
>   sources.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've checked registry keys created for event log sources under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application and removed the one created by my web application. That brought the exception back.

Comment: Glad to help. This event source creation can be done at deployment time so that the web app itself doesn't have to have the necessary permissions to create the event source. In new web apps, I often write to the event log in Application_Start just so it will immediately throw an exception if the event source hasn't been created.

Answer (score 0):

It could be so that the permission to open the event log is caches as long as you do not restart the ASP.NET application and/or IIS. Depends on how you have done in your code.